# WCF Service Issues with Java Client

Tags: wcf, datetime, java-client

This is an interesting problem, and I will do my best to explain. If you have any questions, please ask.

I have written a WCF service that is suppose to communicate with a JAVA client. This service was created via contract first from a WSDL. Now, according to the WCF test client everything works, even testing on a PHP client works as well. But when it comes to the Java client, the request messages and subsequent response messages fail to return: I get a null object SOAP fault. Here is were I think the problem lies:

According to the XSD and WSDL, I have a DateTime value that I am suppose to take in. This dateTime value from the client is of form: 2012-01-01T12:00:00.00Z. Unfortunately, this input is not valid with the built in .NET datetime. So, to get around this, I changed my code to take in a string datatype, convert that string to a Datetime to send it to the database, get a response from the database in that dateTime and convert it back to a string for the response to return a value that is like the one that was inputted.

I built a logger to check to see if the messages were being sent to and from my wcf service. From that, I have identified that messages from the client were not being received. My only guess is that it is because of the datetime issue.

Is there a way to take in a dateTime datatype in the format: 2012-01-01T12:00:00.000Z? If i can, then that will mean that the request will match my datatype and maybe it will work.

Here is some code:

```
    public partial class findSeatsRequest
{

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineData", Order=0, Name="departAirport")]
    public string DepartAirport;

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineData", Order=1, Name="arriveAirport")]
    public string ArriveAirport;

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineMessage", Order=2, Name="earliestDepartTime")]
    public string EarliestDepartTime;

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineMessage", Order=3, Name="latestDepartTime")]
    public string LatestDepartTime;

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineMessage", Order=4, Name="minimumSeatsAvailable")]
    public int MinimumSeatsAvailable;

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineMessage", Order=5, Name="maximumFlightsToReturn")]
    public int MaximumFlightsToReturn;

    public findSeatsRequest()
    {
    }

    public findSeatsRequest(string departAirport, string arriveAirport, string earliestDepartTime, string latestDepartTime, int minimumSeatsAvailable, int maximumFlightsToReturn)
    {
        this.DepartAirport = departAirport;
        this.ArriveAirport = arriveAirport;
        this.EarliestDepartTime = earliestDepartTime;
        this.LatestDepartTime = latestDepartTime;
        this.MinimumSeatsAvailable = minimumSeatsAvailable;
        this.MaximumFlightsToReturn = maximumFlightsToReturn;
    }
}


    public partial class findSeatsResponse
{

    [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://soa.cs.uwf.edu/airlineData", Order=0, Name="flight")]
    [XmlElementAttribute("flight")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<flightType> Flight;

    public findSeatsResponse()
    {
    }

    public findSeatsResponse(System.Collections.Generic.List<flightType> flight)
    {
        this.Flight = flight;
    }
}

        public virtual findSeatsResponse findSeats(findSeatsRequest request)
    {
        string departAirport = request.DepartAirport;
        string arriveAirport = request.ArriveAirport;
        string earliestDepartTime = request.EarliestDepartTime;
        string latestDepartTime = request.LatestDepartTime;
        int minimumSeatsAvailable = request.MinimumSeatsAvailable;
        int maximumFlightsToReturn = request.MaximumFlightsToReturn;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<flightType> flight = new List<flightType>();
        EventLogger log = new EventLogger();

        findSeatsRequest inValue = new findSeatsRequest();
        inValue.DepartAirport = departAirport;
        inValue.ArriveAirport = arriveAirport;
        inValue.EarliestDepartTime = earliestDepartTime;
        inValue.LatestDepartTime = latestDepartTime;
        inValue.MinimumSeatsAvailable = minimumSeatsAvailable;
        inValue.MaximumFlightsToReturn = maximumFlightsToReturn;

        string latestT = inValue.LatestDepartTime.Replace("T", " ");
        string latestZ = latestT.Replace("Z", "");
        DateTime _latestDepartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(latestZ, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string earliestT = inValue.EarliestDepartTime.Replace("T", " ");
        string earliestZ = earliestT.Replace("Z", "");
        DateTime _earliestDepartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(earliestZ, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        log.WriteToDataBase(DateTime.Now, "FindSeats", 1, "This is the request: " + inValue);


        //Check Maximum Flights
        if (inValue.MaximumFlightsToReturn > 100 | inValue.MaximumFlightsToReturn < 0)
        {
            throw new FaultException(
                "You cannot select more than 100 flights to return, or the maximum flights to return is negative.",
                new FaultCode("OutOfRange"));
        }

        // Check Minimum Seats Available.
        if (inValue.MinimumSeatsAvailable < 0)
        {
            throw new FaultException(
                "You minimum seats available cannot be negative.",
                new FaultCode("OutOfRange"));
        }

        // Check for valid Departure Airport
        if (departAirport != null && departAirport != "ANY")
        {
            try
            {
                string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

                conn.Open();

                string check = "SELECT DepartAirport FROM Flight WHERE DepartAirport='" + departAirport + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(check, conn);
                cmd.CommandText = check;
                SqlDataReader depAirport;
                depAirport = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (depAirport.HasRows == false)
                {
                    throw new FaultException(
                        "Invalid Airport code used.",
                        new FaultCode("Invalid Text Entry"));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        // Check for valid Arrival Airport
        if (arriveAirport != null && arriveAirport != "ANY")
        {
            try
            {
                string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

                conn.Open();

                string check = "SELECT ArriveAirport FROM Flight WHERE ArriveAirport='" + arriveAirport + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(check, conn);
                cmd.CommandText = check;
                SqlDataReader arrAirport;
                arrAirport = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (arrAirport.HasRows == false)
                {
                    throw new FaultException(
                        "Invalid Airport code used.",
                        new FaultCode("Invalid Text Entry"));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_NewFindSeats", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DepartureAirport", inValue.DepartAirport));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ArrivalAirport", inValue.ArriveAirport));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EarliestDepTime", _earliestDepartTime));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LatestDepTime", _latestDepartTime));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@minSeatsAvailable", inValue.MinimumSeatsAvailable));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxFlightsRequested", inValue.MaximumFlightsToReturn));

            using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    flightType Flight = new flightType();

                    Flight.FlightId = sqlReader.GetString(0);
                    Flight.DepartAirport = sqlReader.GetString(1);
                    Flight.ArriveAirport = sqlReader.GetString(2);
                    Flight.DepartTime = sqlReader.GetDateTime(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
                    Flight.ArriveTime = sqlReader.GetDateTime(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
                    Flight.FlightSeatsAvailable = sqlReader.GetInt32(5);
                    Flight.FlightSeatPriceUSD = sqlReader.GetDouble(6);

                    flight.Add(Flight);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Null data in a web service usually means confused namespaces. Look at the network traffic with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) or some such to see the difference between the PHP client and the Java client.

Comment: I thought that too and forgot to mention it, but I have another service operation that works fine with the JAVA client. So, I think that my eliminates the invalid namespace issue right?

Comment: No, it does not eliminate it. Please take a look at the network traffic.

Comment: Hiya Saunders, I did what you recommended and there were no material differences in the requests vs responses. I did test my theory about the DataTypes tho, and found that when I changed the request parameters to take in a DateTime, the request message was getting through, but tanked at the response because the Database did not recognize the dateTime string that is being inputted from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular problem, the issue wasn't anything I thought it was in the beginning. Firstly, had to use WrapperNames in my C# code's request operations and the names I used were incorrect.

Secondly, I needed to specify SOAP Body encoding which I had to do within my Interface layer.

```
 [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true, Style=OperationFormatStyle.Document ,Use=OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
```